# Fill a column with continous index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, index

Imagine the followign table:

#### `tmp_migration.asset`

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ id       ║ ...many other columns... ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║       15 ║                      ... ║
║       16 ║                      ... ║
║       17 ║                      ... ║
║       18 ║                      ... ║
║    10020 ║                      ... ║
║    10021 ║                      ... ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

You see, the index doesn't start at 1, has gaps, etc.

## Problem

I want to add a new column `tempId` with a continous index. The table has 80m rows. How can I do that? I googled alot of things and ended up nowhere.

## Background

The table is part of a data migration project. `tmp_migration` is a temporary schema created as the source of the data migration. In the current step I'm trying to copy over from `tmp_migration.asset` to `public.asset` while doing data transformation. I'm using a combined `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` query for that.

The problem with that is, it takes several hours (80m rows) and I don't receive any progress notification during the run. To solve that, I wanted to use "pagination". In the bash, which is calling `psql` with the insert/select script, I created a loop which sets borders passed to the script.

I started with using limit / offset by adding

```sql
LIMIT :limit
OFFSET :offset;
```

to the script, but this slows dramatically down after being at higher "pages". So, it is advised to use `WHERE` on your PK over limit/offset. However, for this I need a continous PK, which I have not. Thus, I thought of adding a temporary consistent index.

Maybe there are other solutions that I don't see right now. Would be very happy about assistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, other_field INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (3,333),(55,555),(777,777);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | other_field |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 333 |
> | 55 | 555 |
> | 777 | 777 |

> ```
> ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN continuous INT;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | other_field | continuous |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 333 | *null* |
> | 55 | 555 | *null* |
> | 777 | 777 | *null* |

> ```
> UPDATE test
> SET continuous = calculate_rownumber.rownumber
> FROM ( SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rownumber
>        FROM test ) calculate_rownumber
> WHERE test.id = calculate_rownumber.id;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | other_field | continuous |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 333 | 1 |
> | 55 | 555 | 2 |
> | 777 | 777 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b040eb3d6580019f96472da8fae8fb52)*

Comment: Wow, thanks alot! I'm adding an index to this `continous` column. But this works perfectly.

Comment: Hm, I'm having difficulties to run this on the dataset with 80m rows. I'm receiving "could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp20298.2261": No space left on device". I am on AWS RDS with instance db.t3.medium, so I have no access to the underyling machine. Any idea why it consumes disk space?

Comment: @agoldev Sorry, I cannot help you with this problem. *why it consumes disk space?* I do not use Postgre, and I'm too lazy for to read the documentation for to find a reason.

Comment: That's alright. I will do the research. However, maybe you know a different approach which I could test for comparison.